# Draw Method using singly linked lists

Tags: c#, linked-list, xna, draw

Background: The game consists of clickable oysters that must be moved to another location on screen where they disappear. The oysters (nodes) have image, rectangle, location, and next-node data. In the draw method I have a counter that represents the number of nodes. The traverse method is called for every iteration. Once the loop completes the variable that traverses the list is reset to the head of the list. Only one of the 25 nodes is drawn.

```
    _oysterSLL.placeholder = _oysterSLL.moveAddress; 
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(Bins.T2DrepresentativeImage, Bins.V2location,     Color.White);

    for (int i = _oysterSLL.count; i > 1; --i)
        {
            _oysterSLL.traverseList(_oysterSLL.moveAddress);
            spriteBatch.Draw(_oysterSLL.moveAddress.T2DrepresentativeImage, _oysterSLL.moveAddress.V2location, Color.White);
        }
    _oysterSLL.moveAddress = _oysterSLL.placeholder;
    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Question: How can I draw every node instead of only the last one?

Thanks for your help. I am fairly new to programming, and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I added the _oysterSLL class code below. The only inherited variable from the utility class used is the count variable which is an int. Thank you for the suggestions and I hope my inclusion of the LinkedList class is helpful. I guess I wanted to avoid using an array as I would like to free memory as the user moves the oysters to the objective. However, I can see how my use of a for loop without using an index is ridiculous.

```
namespace Oyster
{
class LinkedList : Utility
{
    private Oyster _head, _tail, _placeholder, _moveAddress;

    public LinkedList()
    {

    }

    public Oyster head
    {
        get { return _head; }
        set { _head = value;}
    }

    public Oyster tail
    {
        get { return _tail; }
        set { _tail = value; }
    }

    public Oyster placeholder
    {
        get { return _placeholder; }
        set { _placeholder = value; }
    }

    public Oyster moveAddress
    {
        get { return _moveAddress; }
        set { _moveAddress = value; }
    }

    public void oysterAddSLL(Oyster newOyster)
    {
        if (_head == null)
        {
            _head = newOyster;
            _tail = newOyster;
            _placeholder = newOyster;
            _moveAddress = newOyster;
            count++;

        }
        else
        {
            _tail = newOyster;
            _head.Next = _tail;
            _head = _tail;
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void traverseList(Oyster node)
    {
        node = node.Next;
    }

    public void nodeDeletion( Oyster toBeDeleted, Oyster toDirect)
    {
        toDirect.Next = toBeDeleted.Next;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Nahuel lanni pointed out, the problem is likely that you're drawing the same oyster 25 times. You're not looping through the collection, you're merely looping collection.Count times.

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I don't understand your code completely (the variable naming kind of confuses me), or not, but let me try it:

I can see that you are iterating over the collection of oysters, but you always draw the same one.

What's the point of using a `for` loop if you're not gonna be using the index of the loop at all?

I think your problem could be solved by addressing the oyster of every position, basically something like this:

```
for (int i = _oysterSLL.Count; i > 1; --i)
{
    _oysterSLL.traverseList(_oysterSLL[i].moveAddress);
    spriteBatch.Draw(_oysterSLL[i].moveAddress.T2DrepresentativeImage, _oysterSLL[i].moveAddress.V2location, Color.White);
}
```

As you can see, in the draw method I'm now using the index variable (`_oysterSLL[i]`) tot arget each and every object it contains.

But with this in mind, and without the code corresponding to the objects in the `_oysterSLL` collection, it's hard to understand what it does.